# Is $X=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mid x_n\in\{0,1\},\forall n \wedge x_n=1\text{ for at most finitely many $n$}\right\}$ countable or uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider the set $X=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mid x_n\in\{0,1\},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\wedge x_n=1\text{ for at most finitely many $n$}\right\}$ Then what can we say about the cardinality of $X$ (countable or uncountable)?

> My try: I've taken an arbitrary
>   $A=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n,\ldots\}\subseteq X$ which is countable.
>
> Arrange the sets \begin{align}Y_0&=\{(s_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mid s_k\text{ contains no
>  }1's\}\\
> Y_1&=\{(s_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mid s_k\text{ contains exactly one }1's\}\\\vdots \\
>  Y_m&=\{(s_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mid s_k\text{ contains exactly $m$ 1's}\}\\\end{align}
>
> This process must stop for some $m\in\mathbb N$ because each sequence
>   of $X$ contains at most finitely many $1.$
>
> Clearly $A=\bigcup_{i=0}^mY_i$
>
> So if we consider the set $S=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mid x_n\in\{0,1\}\;\forall
>  n\in\mathbb N\text{ and $x_n=1$ for $(m+1)$ values of
>  $n$} \}$
>
> Then $S\not\in A.$ $A$ was an arbitrary countable subset of $X$ and
>   we've shown that $A$ is a proper subset of $X$. Thus any countable
>   subset of $X$ is a proper subset of $X$.
>
> If $X$ is countable then according to the proof, $X$ being a countable
>   subset of $X$, is a proper subset of $X$, a contradiction. Hence $X$
>   must be uncountable.

Comment: The description you gave makes it seem like $X\subset\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. Since each $x_n\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: If $X$ consists of elements that are indexed by the elements of $\mathbb N$, how can we have anything else then $\vert X\vert \leq \vert \mathbb N\vert$?

Comment: @ Prototank Yes. I followed a similar proof from Rudin to prove this.

Comment: If $X\subset\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$, then $|X|\leq 2$. Do you understand that?

Comment: It looks like a confusion between *set* and *sequence*. Although there is no definition of a *set*, we know it contains non-repeating elements. Sequence can contain repeating elements. E.g. $\{1\}$ is a set, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, x_n=1, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a sequence.

Comment: @Prototank do you mean cardinality of $X\le 2$? Isn't it impossible?

Comment: As written, $X\subset\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. I don't think this is what you want. Now, if you have $\lbrace (n,x_n):n\in\mathbb{N},x_n\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace\rbrace$ then this is definitely countable.

Comment: @rtybaseThe sequences of the set $X$ are 0 & 1.

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee you ask about cardinality, which is, generally, defined for  *set*s. *Sequence* can be seen as a function (*set* theoretic definition of the function) $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow S$, where $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ (or any other *set*) s.t. $f(n)=x_n$. With the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ it makes sense to talk about the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: @Prototank As I said a similar proof is given in Rudin: If $X$ is the set of sequences whose elements are the digits $0$ & $1$ then $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee Before anyone can help you, you need to be clear about what you mean. For example: Is $x_n$ defined to be a sequence or a number?

Comment: @rtybase $X$ is the set of sequences having the properties that every element of these sequences is 0 & 1 and each sequence contains at most finite number of 1.

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee then I'd suggest an edit so that $X=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mid x_n\in\{0,1\} ...\right\}$

Comment: @rtybase Sorry for that ambiguity, I've just edited my post. Please verify it.

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee let me fix it ;)

Comment: Let $A=\{10000\dots,110000\dots,1110000\dots,1111000\dots,\dots\}$. This is a countable subset of $X$, but it is not contained in the union of finitely many $Y_i$.

Comment: @Steve Kass The sequences look like $\{1,0,1,0,\ldots\}$ , $\{1,1,0,0,\ldots\}$ etc.

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee I finished my updates. Could you check it please? Also please pay attention to the usage of *set* and *sequence* in the text.

Comment: @rtybase Thank you so much for suggesting edits.

Comment: I was just trying to be concise. Let $A$ be the countable set of sequences $x_1=(1,0,0,\dots)$, $x_2=(1,1,0,0,\dots)$, $x_3=(1,1,1,0,0,\dots)$, ..., $x_k=(1,1,\dots,1,1,0,0,\dots)$ ($k$ ones, then all zeros), etc. This $A$ is a subset of $X$, but it is not contained in the union of finitely many $Y_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ (i.e. the collection of the finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$) is **countable**. Clearly $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}^{(2)},\mathbb{N}^{(3)},\ldots$ are countable, so each element of $\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ can be identified with a couple of natural numbers: the first natural number is the number $k$ of elements of such subset and the second number is the index of such subset among the elements of $\mathbb{N}^{(k)}$. It follows that
$$ \left|\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\mathbb{N})\right| = \left|\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\right|=|\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0.$$

Comment: Could you please explain the flaws in my proof?

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee: simply, your contradiction is not a contradiction. $2\mathbb{N}$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and still both $\mathbb{N}$ and $2\mathbb{N}$ are countable, for instance.

Comment: I said if all countable subsets of a set are the proper subsets of $X$, then $X$ is uncountable. Please have a look at my post where I've proven it that $X$ can't be countable.

Comment: In your example, $\mathbb N$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb N$ but it is not a proper subset of itself.

Comment: If a set has the same cardinality of a proper subset then such set is infinite, not uncountable. The approach above clearly shows that $\mathcal{P}_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ has the same cardinality of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, and I dare you to say that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable!